# tagName error only in IE8 on certain

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-ajax

I have a page which uses MS Ajax to pull content from a web service on the server. This works well on most machines, but does not work in IE8 on specific machines. I have disabled all plugins on these machines and several other suggestions from around the net, but nothing works.

I get the "tagName is not an object" on line 73. When I turn on script debuging, I get the error in the following code:

```
Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor = function Sys$Net$XMLHttpExecutor() {
/// <summary locid="M:J#Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor.#ctor" />
if (arguments.length !== 0) throw Error.parameterCount();
Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor.initializeBase(this);
var _this = this;
this._xmlHttpRequest = null;
this._webRequest = null;
this._responseAvailable = false;
this._timedOut = false;
this._timer = null;
this._aborted = false;
this._started = false;
this._onReadyStateChange = (function () {

    if (_this._xmlHttpRequest.readyState === 4 ) {
        try {
            if (typeof(_this._xmlHttpRequest.status) === "undefined") {
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(ex) {
            return;
        }

        _this._clearTimer();
        _this._responseAvailable = true;
        try {
            _this._webRequest.completed(Sys.EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        finally {
            if (_this._xmlHttpRequest != null) {
                _this._xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = Function.emptyMethod;
                _this._xmlHttpRequest = null;
```

The error is on the last finally line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug with jQuery v1.3.2 and IE8.
Upgrading to v1.4.0 solved the issue.